# Java equivalent of C#'s Type?

Tags: java, types

How do you get and check an object's type in Java, as you can using `Type t = obj.GetType();` in C#?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`getClass()`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29). It returns the runtime class of the object.

Answer (score 4):

`Class clazz = obj.getClass();`

Answer (score 3):

`.getClass()`..

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it fair to actually answer `Class<?>`?

> Returns:
>   The Class object that represents the runtime class of this object.